# deselect row names in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I would like to use  `dplyr` filter to deselect rows that are not in a vector. Consider the following dataframe:

```
    set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(x = sample.int(100,10, replace = F), y  = sample.int(100,10, replace = F)) %>% `rownames<-`(LETTERS[1:10])
```

So, in order to exclude the rows `F` and `J` rows, I should write the following code:

```
df %>% filter(row.names(.) %in% c("A","B","C","D","E","G","H","I"))
```

I wonder if there is any way to use `not in`  and directly deselect the unwanted columns rather than using a vector of wanted columns.

Comment: Just put ``!`` before ``row.names``

Comment: ... and brackets may be helpful too:  `!(row.names(.) %in% c("A","B","C","D","E","G","H","I"))`.

Answer (score 1):

```r
df <- data.frame(x = sample.int(100,10, replace = F), y  = sample.int(100,10, replace = F))
row.names(df) <- LETTERS[1:10]

# base R
df[!row.names(df) %in% c("F", "J"), ]
#>    x  y
#> A  1 35
#> B 40 51
#> C 21 34
#> D 30 46
#> E 51 76
#> G 64 78
#> H 96 89
#> I 98 66

# dplyr
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(!row.names(.) %in% c("F", "J"))
#>    x  y
#> A  1 35
#> B 40 51
#> C 21 34
#> D 30 46
#> E 51 76
#> G 64 78
#> H 96 89
#> I 98 66
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @Abbas does this answer your question?